# PTC Creo PZV file view in browser?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, plugins

i have one app installed which is using arbortext ptc isoview /creo plugin to show files, so i wanted to make app to take snapshot of it in my IE, but cant find the way to load pzv file, if you just drag and drop it, does not work, i also tryed loadin via html, but seems my params are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

solved, by ripping 3 java scripts and displaying full screen pvz file in webbrowser and then taking snapshot